# Error "else" without "if"

Tags: java, if-statement

I have this program set up and i need help with 2 errors that i am getting

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenOdd { 
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("---EvenOdd--- /n");
        System.out.printf("Enter a whole number: ");
        c = in.nextInt();
    }

    public static EvenOdd (int num) {
        int c = num;

        if (int.class) 
            (c/2)*2 = c;

        System.out.println("is even.");

        else (c)
            System.out.println("is odd");

        return EvenOdd;
    }
}
```

```
C:\Users\Desktop\EvenOdd.java:28: error: not a statement
else (c)

C:\Users\Desktop\EvenOdd.java:28: error: 'else' without 'if'
else (c)

2 errors
```

Comment: Use braces. There are 2 statements following the 'if'.

Comment: i tried but it keeps giving me more and more errors

Comment: This is not proper Java syntax at all. The expression after the `if` should be *`boolean`*, and there is not supposed to be an expression (in parentheses) after an `else`, only a statement. See [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Comment: What is "(c)" in `else (c)`? This doesn't look like valid java syntax

Answer (score 2):

Your else doesn't make sense. First of all, you are not using braces, but also your boolean logic does not make sense. Just adding braces will not make your code compile.

I think this rewrite is the closest to what you have

```
public static boolean EvenOdd (int num) {
    // Here your calculation is done
    boolean isEven = (c/2)*2 == c;

    if (isEven) {
        System.out.println("is even.");
    } else if (!isEven) {
        // Using 'else if' for a boolean parameter does not make much sense
        // but i'll leave it here to explain the syntax
        System.out.println("is odd");
    }
    return isEven;
}
```

However, the most common way to check for odd or even is using the modulus operator. And if i make the entire code a bit more java-ish, you'd end up with (for example method-naming)

```
/**
 * Check if the given number is even.
 * @param num the number to check
 * @return whether num is an even number
 */
public static boolean isEven (int num) {
    if ((x % 2) == 0) {
        System.out.println("is even.");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("is odd");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    try{
        System.out.println("---EvenOdd---");
        
        System.out.print("Enter a whole number: ");
        int c = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        evenOdd(c);
    }finally{
        keyboard.close();
    }
}

public static void evenOdd(int num)
{
    int c = num;
    if ((c/2)*2 == c){
        System.out.println("is even.");
    }else {
        System.out.println("is odd");
    }
}
```

Output:

for the input value `5`

> ---EvenOdd---
>
> Enter a whole number: 5
>
> is odd

for the input value `4`

> ---EvenOdd---
>
> Enter a whole number: 4
>
> is even.

**Continued Reading**

There are several problems with the original code and I will attempt to explain them in line order.

Original code for reference:

```
public class EvenOdd { 
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("---EvenOdd--- /n");
        System.out.printf("Enter a whole number: ");
        c = in.nextInt();
    }

    public static EvenOdd (int num) {
        int c = num;

        if (int.class) 
            (c/2)*2 = c;

        System.out.println("is even.");

        else (c)
            System.out.println("is odd");

        return EvenOdd;
    }
}
```

First we have this line

`System.out.print("---EvenOdd--- /n");`

use of the `.print()` method here, while not illegal is unnecessary because java provides us with `.println()` which automatically creates a new line so we don't have to. (i.e. with "/n")

`System.out.printf("Enter a whole number: ");`

Next you use the `.printf()` method, this prints a formatted output and accepts arguments as a parameter. You aren't using any of the exclusive features of this method so we can achieve the same functionality with `.print()`.

`c = in.nextInt();`

the variable `in` is not defined in this scope, I presume that you meant to use `keyboard.nextInt()`.

`public static EvenOdd (int num) {`

when a method has no return type and the same name as the class it resides in (case sensitive) it is a constructor. Constructors do not require a `return` statement and are invoked with the syntax `new ObjectConstructor()` usually to assign a value to a variable of the same type as the constructor.

```
if (int.class) 
(c/2)*2 = c;
System.out.println("is even.");
else (c)
System.out.println("is odd");
```

This `if-else` block is clearly not even `java` syntax.

first there is no need to cast your result to an `int` and the semicolon at the end of your conditional doesn't belong.

removing these errors brings us to:

```
if (c/2)*2 = c
System.out.println("is even.");
else (c)
System.out.println("is odd");
```

now we need to wrap our conditional in parentheses '`(` and `)`' and rather than use the assignment operator '`=`' we should use the comparison operator '`==`' which returns a `boolean`. Also, the `else` clause does not require a condition, if you would like to use a condition look into `elseif`.

these changes get us to this step.

```
if ((c/2)*2 == c)
System.out.println("is even.");
else
System.out.println("is odd");
```

Now we add proper brackets and we are good to go.

```
if ((c/2)*2 == c){
    System.out.println("is even.");
}else{
    System.out.println("is odd");
}
```